# how to scan test an API using tosca API scan that send data to APIs as multipart/form-data

Tags: tosca

How can we test an API with payload that is a
form-data. In postman, it has an option of what kind of body-data it
is like . How can we do this on Tosca API scan?

Payloads that have key-value

I cant seem to figure out how. Im new to tosca